# BrowserStack: Mac and iOS all browsers does not allow scrolling on parent of inline block elements

Tags: html, css, ios, macos, cross-browser

Here is the weird problem am dealing with and having no idea on how to fix it. Here are my findings.

**Problem:**

I am unable to scroll through child elements on any browser on Mac or iOS devices. Though it is working fine on other platforms.

> I have verified I can have `scrollWidth` greater than the viewport
> width on mac and ios browsers (identical to other platforms).

If you run this code on any browser on any platform except mac or ios it is working fine but it does not scroll on browsers on mac and ios.

Here is the fiddle...

```css
body {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
.container {
  height: auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.parent {
  height: auto;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here we go one more surprise... a simple div having width more than body does not scroll as well.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  line-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div>DIV</div>
```

Comment: Both your snippets are working for me fine in both portrait and landscape on iPad IOS 14.4 Safari.

Comment: Thats a great news Haworth thank you. Then would it be a problem on https://www.browserstack.com/ ? I have almost no idea about mac and ios stuff.

Comment: I honestly don't know as I don't know how that works. Was it browerstack that showed the non-scrolling?

Comment: BrowserStack is a cloud web and mobile testing platform that provides developers the ability to test their websites and mobile applications across on-demand browsers, operating systems and real mobile devices. I tested those snippet on browsers (Safari, Chrome) of Mac OS (14, 13, 12, 11) and iOS devices. For some odd reason I am unable to scroll horizontally on any of them there.

Comment: Yes, I guess emulators are not always to be trusted! Perhaps change your question heading to 'BrowserStack incorrectly reporting that Mac and IOS browsers etc 'as that might help someone. Maybe there's some other forum associated with BrowserStack you should report it to as well? BTW, just had someone test your first snippet on a real Mac and it works.

Comment: Appreciated your time and advice Haworth. Thank you again. Will change it.

Comment: All good then! I am keeping my answer for someone else's usefulness. Many people are comfortable with flex so it may help them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am sorry I have to write my opinion in the answer section. I am not able to give you the solution, I was trying to solve with flex. Sometimes it's working but sometimes it's not.
Also for some reason, the horizontal scrolling is not working in other devices too(checked through my Chrome inspector, from PC).
Just see if my code is working for you.

```css
body {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
.container {
/*   height: auto; */
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.parent {
/*   height: auto; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;
}

.child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 30%;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Forhad Rahman for your suggestion and I tried it on Mac Safari and Mac Chrome but it did not work.

Comment: Your solution might work as am testing them on browserstack not on physical devices (I got none).

Answer (score 0):

Anybody who has come across this question I want to admit as **@a-haworth** submitted his test on physical device and confirmed that both of the snippets are working fine for him and ofcourse **@forhad-rahman** provided a flex based solution (That should work too, I have not tested it on physical device).

**Conclusion:** BrowserStack simulation or browserstack eco system based Apple devices does have some weird problem. Am not quiet sure if simulation or device got anything to do with this issue but I suspect some kind of Gesture or restricted access to devices (by browserstack config) do have something wrong.

If any of you having same problem then must cross check your feature on physical/real device once and then proceed.